# ASP.NET MVC AngularJS. "Кастомный" фильтр под DateRangePicker

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

Привет добрым людям!
Только начал изучать AngularJS и вообще JS вообще.
Вообщем, есть таблица с dir-pagination (ng-repeat), в которой по каждому столбцу привинчена сортировка по ASC, DESC и собственный фильтр. Нужный кусок HTML-кода:

```
    <tr>
        <th>
            <input ng-model="search.country" class="form-control" type="text" />
        </th>
        <th>
            <input ng-model="search.city" class="form-control" type="text" />
        </th>
        <th>
            <input ng-model="search.street" class="form-control" type="text" />
        </th>
        <th>
            <input ng-model="search.house" class="form-control" type="number" />
        </th>
        <th>
            <input ng-model="search.zipcode" class="form-control" type="number" />
        </th>
        <th>
            <input ng-model="search.date" class="form-control" type="text" name="daterange" />
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr dir-paginate="address in addressess|orderBy:sortKey:reverse|filter:search|itemsPerPage:10" current-page="curpage">
        <td ng-class="{'activeColumn': activeColumn === 'country', 'inactiveColumn': activeColumn != 'country'}">{{address.country}}</td>
        <td ng-class="{'activeColumn': activeColumn === 'city', 'inactiveColumn': activeColumn != 'city'}">{{address.city}}</td>
        <td ng-class="{'activeColumn': activeColumn === 'street', 'inactiveColumn': activeColumn != 'street'}">{{address.street}}</td>
        <td ng-class="{'activeColumn': activeColumn === 'house', 'inactiveColumn': activeColumn != 'house'}">{{address.house}}</td>
        <td ng-class="{'activeColumn': activeColumn === 'zipcode', 'inactiveColumn': activeColumn != 'zipcode'}">{{address.zipcode}}</td>
        <td ng-class="{'activeColumn': activeColumn === 'date', 'inactiveColumn': activeColumn != 'date'}">{{address.date }}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

К последней колонке "date" прикрутил DateRangePicker от Bootstrap'а и теперь не могу толком написать фильтр, который будет фильтровать данные в заданном диапазоне.
Уже тону, помогите плиз))

Comment: А проблема то в чём?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

К концу дня башка вообще не варит :( Написал сам за 20 минут)

```
app.filter('dateRange', function () {
    return function (items, startDate, endDate) {
        var retArray = [];

        if (!startDate && !endDate) {
            return items;
        }
        angular.forEach(items, function (obj) {
            var receivedDate = obj.date;
            if (moment(receivedDate).isAfter(startDate) && moment(receivedDate).isBefore(endDate)) {
                retArray.push(obj);
            }
        });
        return retArray;
    }
});
```